# How to create cropped thumbnail with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, image, thumbnails

I'm trying here to create interface to load image and then select area of this image to save cropped thumbnail along with original image. 
To select cropping area I use jquery.Jcrop plugin and it works fine at the  first gaze. 
Then I post relevant x-y width-height data to my php script and trying to save thumbnail with this lines of code:

```
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg(UPLOADED_IMAGE);
$target = imagecreatetruecolor(TWIDTH, THEIGHT);

imagecopyresampled($target,$source,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    TWIDTH,THEIGHT,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

imagejpeg($target, FINAL_THUMBNAIL_DIRECTORY.$targetFile, 100);
```

to ensure that all data is correct:

```
$imageSize =  getimagesize(UPLOADED_IMAGE);
echo UPLOADED_IMAGE . "\n";
echo $imageSize[0] . "x" . $imageSize[1] . "\n";
echo TWIDTH . "x" . THEIGHT . "\n";
echo $_POST['x'] . "x" . $_POST['y'] . " - " . $_POST['w'] . "x" . $_POST['h'] . "\n";
echo FINAL_THUMBNAIL_DIRECTORY.$targetFile . "\n";
exit();
```

[image]

as you may see on this image (result of php script in alert window), all variables passed in my script is valid. UPLOADED_IMAGE is there, available by this link, but final saved image is 200x150 and **solid black**.

What may cause this problem? I'm running around this problem for a few days, although I'm not a php programmer, code looks quite simple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use PHP to create thumbnails. (Cropped to square)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686000/use-php-to-create-thumbnails-cropped-to-square)

Comment: you are not asking for this, but try to use imagemagick instead of gd

Comment: That question is for squared thumbnails. Anyway, my code is quite same, but still not working. May be someone will help me to find the difference

Comment: @rooobertek, thanks, I'll look into it. But still, want to figure out what I did wrong :)